# How to fix build error after moving react native app to new directory?

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-ios

I have a fresh react native app (0.64), initialized using `react-native init`.

All i did was move the root directory to a new location.

Lets say it was initialized in Desktop/Development/App/

then moved to Desktop/NewFolder/App

Now xcode (v12.4) build errors out with this:

> 2021-04-22 21:15:00.972 xcodebuild[49017:1689740] [MT] iPhoneConnect:
> <DVTiOSDevice (0x7ffc4a1332c0), iPhone, iPhone, 14.0.1 (18A393),
> 00008020-001325581A88003A> == END: Underlying device preparation
> errors ==
> ** BUILD FAILED **
>
> The following build commands failed:
> PhaseScriptExecution [CP-User]\ Generate\ Specs /Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestRnMap-duuiecsbjoqdmcgvuyqbhriiigvg/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/FBReactNativeSpec.build/Script-BB599D7FFD9901F8410EF7B25FDA5742.sh
> (1 failure)

Ive tried:

- rm -rf ios/build
- deleting derived data
- restarting xcode
- react-native start --reset-cache

Comment: looks like potentially a cocoapods issue, maybe try deleting Pods/

Comment: if you provide an answer with the reason behind this ill gladly accept @Kai

Answer (score 1):

Try to delete the app from the simulator and re-install.